# how does this recursive statement work?

Tags: python

I have two recursive statements that do the same thing, i understand how the first one works but I am confused on the second case.

1)

```
def recurPower(base, exp):
 '''
 base: int or float.
 exp: int >= 0

 returns: int or float, base^exp
 '''
 # Base case is when exp = 0
 if exp <= 0:
   return 1

 # Otherwise, exp must be > 0, so return 
 #  base* base^(exp-1). This is the recursive case.
 return base * recurPower(base, exp - 1)
```

this first case although it is recalling itself it still leaves a variable "base" behind to multiply every time around the method.

2)

```
def recurPowerNew(base, exp):
'''
base: int or float.
exp: int >= 0

returns: int or float; base^exp
'''
# Base case is when exp = 0
if exp <= 0:
    return 1

# Recursive case 1: exp > 0 and even
elif exp % 2 == 0:
    return recurPowerNew(base*base, exp/2)

# Otherwise, exp must be > 0 and odd, so use the second
#  recursive case.
return base * recurPowerNew(base, exp - 1)
```

In this case I don't understand how it works if it is an **even** number, there is no variable like in the first case that is being acted upon, when the number is even it seems to just constantly give itself different parameters but at no point does it actually address any particular variable such as "base".

do parameters return a value if there is no body in the method?

Comment: `do parameters return a value if there is no body in the method?` parameters do not return values, functions return

Comment: Each return of the recursive function pops a stackframe, and that restores the frame containing `base`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch sorry I still don't quite understand it, this part of the method doesn't contain a base                                                                                elif exp % 2 == 0:
    return recurPowerNew(base*base, exp/2)                                                       it seems to me that it just changes the parameters each time around.

Comment: `base*base` doesn't contain a `base`? Or it doesn't multiply the result of the recursion by another case...

Comment: how does that value leave the parameter though? in the first and the second (the odd part) example the base is outside of the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First parameters don't return values, functions do.

Second, I see where you might be getting confused with recursive problem. Recursion doesn't require that there be a variable "acted" on. As long as recursion eventually reaches the base case it will return a value.

For example here is a useless recursive function that returns 1 for any integer.

```
def foo(n):
  if n <= 1:
    return 1
  else:
    return foo(n-1)
```

foo will return 1 for any integer n, because eventually by subtracting one from an integer we will reach the base case of n < 1.

With recursive problems the key is to think about the base case and make sure that you are approaching the base case on each iteration.

In both of your recursive functions, the base case is an exponent of zero. The second recursive formula is just taking a shortcut to the base case whenever n is even. For every even power you can simply calculate the square of the base and cut the power in half because x^n = (x^2)^(n/2)

Working through an example might make it clear.

Staring with

```
recurPowerNew(2, 10)
```

because exp=10, which is even, the first return value will be:

```
recurPowerNew(2 * 2, 5)
```

this is taking advantage of the fact that 2^10 = (2^2)^5. Now we have to evaluate the new return function. Even though we've only generated a new function, we've made progressed towards the base case of exp = 0. So eventually we expect to get an answer.

Now we have an odd base so the return value is going to be:

```
4 * recurPowerNew(4, 4)
```

Now we again have a function that we have to evaluate, but it's even so 
it just returns a new function.

```
4 * recurPowerNew(4 * 4, 2)
```

Even again.

```
4 * recurPowerNew(16 * 16, 1)
```

An odd function so we get another factor.

```
4 * (256 * recurPowerNew(256, 0))
```

Ah now we are at the base case and there is no more recursion.

```
4 * 256 * 1
```

and we can evaluate the result and get

```
1024
```

The key that makes this work is that on every iteration we got closer to the base case, and we were able to do it much fewer calls because dividing by two reduces the exponent faster than subtracting 1.

Comment: Thank you very much :) also a very helpful outlook on recursion. I would up vote but I don't have enough reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example:

```
print recurPowerNew(3, 4)
```

so `base` is 3 and `exp` is 8.  This will fall into the case you are concerned with, and call:

```
return recurPower(9, 2)
```

... which will also fall into the same case, and call

```
return recurPower(81, 1)
```

ah-ha!  This is the odd case.  So this will call:

```
return 81 * recurPower(81, 0)
```

The second term of the multiplication is 1, so we return 81 all the way up the stack.  If you follow this through, it also works for numbers that are not powers of two.

The point of this, is that it is *much* more efficient than the first method.  It will produce one or two stack frames per bit of the exponent.  The first method will produce `exponent` stack frames!

Incidentally, the second example could be made even more efficient by observing that in case where the exponent is odd, subtracting one will yield an even exponent, so we can just handle that directly:

```
     return base * recurPowerNew(base*base, exp // 2)
```

(use `/` instead of `//` if using Python 2).

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what I was missing. (81,1) eventually it becomes odd and that's how it leaves the parameter.